# Cómo recoger los datos introducidos en un formulario en ASP.NET Web Forms (C#) cuando el usuario hace click en el botón enviar

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

mi duda es cómo puedo recoger los datos introducidos en un formulario en ASP.NET Web Forms (C#) cuando el usuario hace click en el botón enviar.

Ya tengo creado el método del botón al hacer click.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cómo puedo recoger los datos introducidos en un formulario en ASP.NET Web Forms

Como no especificas qué control o qué tipo de datos estás solicitando, el siguiente ejemplo es para recoger el texto de un textbox:

En tu metodo del botón puedes asignarle el texto del textbox a una variable, tal que así:

```
namespace WebForms
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        string valor;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          valor = TextBox1.Text; //<----
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vale, entonces puedo recoger los datos del form y con eso crear un objeto "usuario"  guardarlo en la bbdd de esta forma? :

`protected void ButtonRegistrarNuevoUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          valor1 = TextBoxNombre.Text; 
          valor2 = TextBoxEmail.Text; 
          Usuario user = new Usuario(valor1, valor2, ..........);

          servicioBBDD.GuardarDatos(user);<----------
        }`

Comment: @Carlos Exacto:)